# Merging Datasets with Different Attributes

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have a group of .xls files containing data for different periods of the year. I would like to merge them so that I have all the data in one file. I tried the following code:

```
#create files list
setwd("~/2010")
file.list <- list.files( pattern = ".*\\.xls$", full.names = TRUE )
```

When I continue, I get some warnings but I don't think they are relevent. See below:

```
#read files
> l <- lapply( file.list, readxl::read_excel )
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In read_fun(path = enc2native(normalizePath(path)), sheet_i = sheet,  ... :
  Expecting numeric in F1944 / R1944C6: got '-'
2: In read_fun(path = enc2native(normalizePath(path)), sheet_i = sheet,  ... :
  Expecting numeric in H1944 / R1944C8: got '-'
```

Then, I run the following line and the problems with the attributes pop up:

```
> dt <- data.table::rbindlist( l, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE )
Error in data.table::rbindlist(l, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE) : 
  Class attribute on column 15 of item 4 does not match with column 15 of item 1.
```

Can someone help me to fix this? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps try `bind_rows()` from `{dplyr}` instead of `rbindlist`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to bind together two datasets, the classes of the columns must match. Yours apparently do not. So you somehow need to address these mismatches.

Because you did not supply a `col_types` argument to `read_xl::read_excel`, it is guessing column types. I assume you expect the columns to be the same class in all of the data frames (otherwise, why bind them?) in which case you could pass a `col_types` argument so that `read_xl::read_excel` doesn't have to guess.

The error messages here are useful: I think they are saying that a column was guessed to be numeric but then the parser encountered a "-". Maybe this led to the column being assigned class `"character"`. Perhaps "-" appears in the raw data to indicate a missing value. Then passing `na = c("", "-")` to `read_xl::read_excel` could resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wrote `l <- lapply( file.list, readxl::read_excel, col_types = "numeric ") ` and it worked. However, I have one column that contains the name of the asset and I lost it by running this. Do you know how to fix it? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `col_types` accepts a vector, so if there are 10 columns and the first one is the asset name, you can pass `col_types = c("character", rep("numeric", 9))`.